# Dictionary creating from the data in python

Tags: python

I have HTML data:

```
comp_row = """
  <div class="row odd">
    <ul>
      <li class="ttl"><a href="/companies/20-microns/533022">20 Microns</a></li>
      <li>533022</li>
      <li>20MICRONS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="row odd">
    <ul>
      <li class="ttl"><a href="/companies/3i-infotech/532628">3i Infotech</a></li>
      <li>532628</li>
      <li>3IINFOTECH</li>
    </ul>
  </div>"""
```

expected data:

```
[533022 = {
"name":"20 Microns",
"bsecode":533022,
"nsecode":"20MICRONS"
},

532628= {
"name":"3i-infotech",
"bsecode":532628,
"nsecode":"3IINFOTECH"
}]
```

Can I achieve the data like this and is this the good format to hold data like this or any other format to access later?

Comment: I recommend to use JSON as the output format: `{"533022": {"name": ...}, "532628": {"name": ...}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The Beautiful Soup 4 library is very good for parsing HTML like that

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
comp_row = """
<div class="row odd">
  <ul>
  <li class="ttl"><a href="/companies/20-microns/533022">20 Microns</a></li><li>533022</li><li>20MICRONS</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="row odd">
  <ul>
      <li class="ttl"><a href="/companies/3i-infotech/532628">3i Infotech</a></li><li>532628</li><li>3IINFOTECH</li>
  </ul>
</div>
"""

html = BeautifulSoup(comp_row, "lxml")

data = {}

for row in html.find_all("div"):
  link = row.find("a")
  nsecode = row.find_all("li")[-1].text
  name = link.text
  bsecode = int(link["href"].split("/")[3])
  data[bsecode] = {
    "name": name,
    "bsecode": bsecode,
    "nsecode": nsecode,
  }
```